# Table-of-Contents items appearing flush against the edge of the left margin

Tags: table-of-contents, amsart

I am using `\documentclass{amsart}` and want my table of contents subsections to be indented slightly beneath the sections. Right now, all the sections and subsections are equally flush to the left side. I still want the page numbers to be aligned though. What is the proper code?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: this is a known problem, but unfortunately, i won't be able to research the answer until i return to the office after november 7.  the approach involves redefining the appropriate `\l@<section` command(s).

Comment: @barbara I know it is quite old, but are you interested in looking into the matter?

Comment: @barbarabeeton Any news here?

Comment: this question is the same as [Correct the zigzag-form align of a TOC (article)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/324907/579) which is also still unanswered, but the reason is given there in the comments.

Comment: Thanks to the claim arose now there's at least a _sledgehammer solution_ in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/400896/116815) be egreg...