# Correct the zigzag-form align of a TOC (article)?

Tags: table-of-contents, amsart

I would like to obtain an advice regarding the TOC for an article. I wonder if the following serpent-like output caused by numbers of subsections being longer than those of sections is my mistake or is intended like that by `amsart`? If not, I'd like to know, even manually, how to correct it? I have tried a double title (one in square brackets having more space before the text) but no result.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
% \usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[english]{babel}


\begin{document}


 \tableofcontents

%% -------------------------- 
\section{First Movement}
 \subsection{Allegro con brio} 
  \subsection{Allegro senza brio} 
  \section{Second Movement}
  \subsection{Adagio}
  \subsection{Piu adagio}
  \subsection{Ancora piu adagio}
  \section{Third Movement: ``la sveglia''}
 \section{Finale}
 \subsection{Prestisisimo}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  As it stands your question is asking for opinion  based answers and as such is off topic.  If you changed the question to just the "how?" part, then it would be on topic.  Incidentally, it is no the width of the numbers that is causing this, it is a design decision from a reputable institution and  the indentations are based on some fixed indents that depend on the section level.

Comment: @AndrewSwann -- actually, this is not a conscious design decision.  it is the unfortunate consequence of a delay in making an appropriate decision -- no changes should be made without written specs.  the specs were not forthcoming within the time available to complete and post the class file, and unfortunately, updates have not been made regularly since then.  this is *definitely* on the list for improvement!  (but reasonable code does not yet exist.)

Comment: the question [Table-of-Contents items appearing flush against the edge of the left margin](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/141009/579) is essentially identical, and should be closed as a duplicate if this question gets an upvoted answer.

Comment: @barbarabeeton now egreg gives a _"sledgehammer solution"_...

Answer (score 2):

A sledgehammer solution:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\l@section}{\@tocline{1}{0pt}{0pc}{}{}}
\renewcommand{\l@subsection}{\@tocline{2}{0pt}{0pc}{}{}}
\renewcommand{\tocsection}[3]{%
  \indentlabel{\@ifnotempty{#2}{\makebox[3em][l]{\ignorespaces#1 #2.}}}#3%
}
\let\tocsubsection\tocsection
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{First Movement}
\subsection{Allegro con brio} 
\subsection{Allegro senza brio} 

\section{Second Movement}
\subsection{Adagio}
\subsection{Pi\`u adagio}
\subsection{Ancora pi\`u adagio}

\section{Third Movement: ``la sveglia''}

\section{Finale}
\subsection{Prestissimo}

\end{document}
```

However, this should be refined when the number of sections is larger than nine; not so simple a task, if one wants it to be as general as possible.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

another sledgehammer solution, but indenting the subsections as was originally intended for the ams document classes.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\l@section}{\@tocline{1}{0pt}{2pc}{}{}}
\renewcommand{\l@subsection}{\@tocline{2}{0pt}{3.5pc}{}{}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

 \tableofcontents

%% -------------------------- 
\section{First Movement}
 \subsection{Allegro con brio} 
  \subsection{Allegro senza brio} 
  \section{Second Movement}
  \subsection{Adagio}
  \subsection{Piu adagio}
  \subsection{Ancora piu adagio}
  \section{Third Movement: ``la sveglia''}
 \section{Finale}
 \subsection{Prestisisimo}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

the ams document classes were originally intended to set the indentations automatically (after two runs) by posting to the `.aux` file the actual widths of the varions "section" numbers, and reading in these values on the next pass.  the current version of the classes does write the information into the `.aux` file, but it never gets assigned to the correct elements.  clearly a bug, but one that hasn't yet been deciphered.

Comment: My Italian self cries seeing “piu” without an accent and “Prestisisimo”. `;-)`

Comment: just copied from the original, sigh.  should have been able to catch the misspelled "prestissimo" though.  (my familiarity with italian is only slightly more robust than my familiarity with spanish -- near zero.  more comfortable in somewhat more northerly climes.)